# Sending message to HTTP Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I would like to send a `message` to an `HTTP triggered Google Cloud Function`. Specifically I want to tell the function when a file version has changed so that the function loads the new version of the file in memory.

I thought about updating an `environment variable` as a way of sending that message but it is not so straightforward to run an `update-env-vars` since this needs to be done in the context of the function's project.

Also I thought of using a `database` which sounds like too much for a single variable and using a simple `text file` in storage with the current version which sounds too little. Any other idea?

Comment: Can you describe a bit more, please? What for you would like to "send" a message to a cloud function? What the cloud function is supposed to do after that message is "recieved"?

Comment: So the idea is that there is a version of a file, if that version changes i need to load the file again. So I need to communicate the new version to the Cloud function, the message is the version of the file. Other option would be a database but thought it would be an overkill for only one variable.

Comment: @al-dann check above

Comment: Are these files in Cloud Storage?

Comment: @FrancoPiccolo What kind of function are you implementing? It looks like if you try preserving some state within it, and it is something against the "spirit" of the function concept. Why do not create a [http](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http) based function, for example, and pass all the necessary information as parameters of the invocation?

Comment: @CaioT yes they are in GS

Comment: @jccampanero but the caller doesn’t know the right version of the file.

Comment: I understand Franco, thank you. So, the idea is that the function will serve that file and it need to know that it changed, is that right? And, from a different point of view, if you are using GS, why do not listen for a [`google.storage.object.finalize`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#object_finalize) event and reload the file then?

Comment: @jccampanero, yes that is the idea, but this solution doesn't guarantee that all the functions alive at some point will listen to the event right?

Answer (score 2):

According to the conversation in the comments section, I believe the best way to achieve what you are looking for is a gcs notification triggering PubSub.

```
gsutil notification create -t TOPIC_NAME -f json gs://BUCKET_NAME
```

PubSub will get notified based on event types and this I believe it will depend on what you consider a new version of the file (metadata changes? new blob will be created?)

Basically, you can pass the -e flag in the command above which indicates the event type:

> OBJECT_FINALIZE   Sent when a new object (or a new generation of an
> existing object) is successfully created in the bucket. This includes
> copying or rewriting an existing object. A failed upload does not
> trigger this event.
>
> OBJECT_METADATA_UPDATE    Sent when the metadata of an existing object
> changes.

That means, any file upload or metadata change in GCS it will trigger PubSub which triggers your Cloud Function. Function example to pull message from PubSub

```
def hello_pubsub(event, context):
    
    import base64

    print("""This Function was triggered by messageId {} published at {} to {}
    """.format(context.event_id, context.timestamp, context.resource["name"]))

    if 'data' in event:
        name = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    else:
        name = 'World'
    print('Hello {}!'.format(name))
```

Documents for reference:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#functions_calling_pubsub-python

Comment: Hey CaioT thanks for the detailed answer, but my use case is not to trigger the function it is to change the "state" of the function as mentioned by jccampanero in a comment.

Comment: Just edited the question phrasing which was leading to confusion sorry.